# error in linq query c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

i get want to join between data to list or list to list in asp.net c# with linq
and it gives to me error

that code i write:

```
var accounts = (from r in AccAffList 
                join b in topicalDB.Affs on r.Item2 equals b.AffId
                select r).ToList();
var transactions = DB.VtigerBotransactions.ToList();
var details = from a in accounts join c in transactions on a.Item1 equals c.Accountid select c;
```

and that error i get :

> Error 8   The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is
>   incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'.

what is wrong it?

Comment: "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect" - did you check that?

Comment: What are the types of `topicalDB.Affs` and `b.AffId`.?

Comment: both in db BIGINT or in c# long

Comment: It seems that `Affs.AffId` and `AccAffList.Item2` are diferent types (One string and one int for example). Make sure them both are the same

Comment: error is in var transactions

Comment: u right i had diffrent type but in transactions :)
thank you